# Align Textview drawable and text to baseline bottom?

Tags: android

I have a `textView` with an image and text, I want to align text with the baseline of the image. I am trying but unable to do this. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/date"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

[image: Textview with image]

I want to text and image like this, they share the same baseline:

[image]

Comment: did you try `android:gravity="center"` to your `TextView`

Comment: @NileshRathod yes I tried, but I want to set text to baseline of drawable.

Comment: can u share your expected output with question

Comment: you cannot do that with `android:drawableStart` (compound drawables in general)

Comment: @NileshRathod I have updated my question with expected output. Please check.

Comment: @Furqan check the link at the top

Comment: then use `android.text.style.ImageSpan`

Comment: set android:gravity="bottom" of your linearlayout and set your all textview height wrap_content

Answer (score -2):

Try Below:

Use `android:drawableTop` to set Image at top.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/progress_image"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Below Text"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
```

Comment: Read the question again my friend